# Найти более оптимальный алгоритм

Tags: java, алгоритм

## Вопрос

Мне дали задачу, текст и мое решение приведен ниже, задачу желательно решить с минимально возможной сложностью алгоритма.

> Требуется, чтобы асимптотическое время работы полученного решения было линейным, или близким к линейному.

Я же реализовал решение за время O(n^2), несмотря на это, мое решение приняли, но, как сделать проще, никак не могу додуматься. Интересуюсь для своего развития, может кто-то подсказать пожалуйста - можно ли ее вообще решить за линейное время и как это сделать?

## Задача

Имеется n пользователей, каждому из них соответствует список email-ов(всего у всех пользователей m email-ов). 
Например:
user1 ->xxx@ya.ru,foo@gmail.com,lol@mail.ru 
user2 ->foo@gmail.com,ups@pisem.net
user3 ->xyz@pisem.net,vasya@pupkin.com
user4 ->ups@pisem.net,aaa@bbb.ru
user5 ->xyz@pisem.net

Считается, что если у двух пользователей есть общий email, значит это
один и тот же пользователь. Требуется построить
и реализовать алгоритм, выполняющий слияние пользователей. На выходе
должен быть список пользователей с их email-ами (такой же как на
входе).
В качестве имени объединенного пользователя можно брать любое из
исходных имен. Список email-ов пользователя должен содержать только
уникальные email-ы.
Параметры n и m произвольные, длина конкретного списка email-ов никак
не ограничена.
Требуется, чтобы асимптотическое время работы полученного решения было
линейным, или близким к линейному.

Возможный ответ на задачу в указанном примере:
user1 ->xxx@ya.ru,foo@gmail.com,lol@mail.ru,ups@pisem.net,aaa@bbb.ru
user3 ->xyz@pisem.net,vasya@pupkin.com

## Мое решение

```
public class Mail {
public static Map<String, Set<String>> merge(Map<String, Set<String>> mails) {
    if (mails.size() < 2) {
        return mails;
    }
    Map<String, Set<String>> temp = new HashMap<>();
    for (String key : mails.keySet()) {
        int f = 0;
        if (temp.size() == 0) {
            temp.put(key, mails.get(key));
        } else {
            for (String tempKey : temp.keySet()) {
                if (containsAny(temp.get(tempKey), mails.get(key))) {
                    Set<String> tmp = new HashSet<>(temp.get(tempKey));
                    tmp.addAll(mails.get(key));
                    temp.put(tempKey, tmp);
                    f++;
                }
            }
        }
        if (f == 0) {
            temp.put(key, mails.get(key));
        }
    }
    return temp;
}

private static boolean containsAny(Set<String> arr1, Set<String> arr2) {
    for (String value : arr1) {
        for (String s : arr2) {
            if (value.equals(s)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

## Тесты

```
public class MailTest {
@Test
public void whenMerge() {
    Map<String, Set<String>> input = new HashMap<>();
    Set<String> user1 = new HashSet<>();
    Set<String> user2 = new HashSet<>();
    Set<String> user3 = new HashSet<>();
    input.put("User1", user1);
    input.put("User2", user2);
    input.put("User3", user3);
    Map<String, Set<String>> expected = new HashMap<>();
    Set<String> user2Ex = new HashSet<>();
    Set<String> user3Ex = new HashSet<>();
    expected.put("User2", user2Ex);
    expected.put("User3", user3Ex);
    input = Mail.merge(input);
    assertThat(input.get("User2"), is(expected.get("User2")));
    assertThat(input.get("User3"), is(expected.get("User3")));
}

@Test
public void whenNotMerge() {
    Map<String, Set<String>> input = new HashMap<>();
    Set<String> user1 = new HashSet<>();
    Set<String> user2 = new HashSet<>();
    Set<String> user3 = new HashSet<>();
    input.put("User1", user1);
    input.put("User2", user2);
    input.put("User3", user3);
    Map<String, Set<String>> expected = new HashMap<>();
    Set<String> user1Ex = new HashSet<>();
    Set<String> user2Ex = new HashSet<>();
    Set<String> user3Ex = new HashSet<>();
    expected.put("User1", user1Ex);
    expected.put("User2", user2Ex);
    expected.put("User3", user3Ex);
    input = Mail.merge(input);
    assertThat(input.get("User1"), is(expected.get("User1")));
    assertThat(input.get("User2"), is(expected.get("User2")));
    assertThat(input.get("User3"), is(expected.get("User3")));
}

@Test
public void whenOnlyOneUser() {
    Map<String, Set<String>> input = new HashMap<>();
    Set<String> user1 = new HashSet<>();
    input.put("User1", user1);
    HashMap<String, Set<String>> expected = new HashMap<>();
    Set<String> user1Ex = new HashSet<>();
    expected.put("User1", user1Ex);
    input = Mail.merge(input);
    assertThat(input.get("User1"), is(expected.get("User1")));
}

@Test
public void whenOnlyZeroUsers() {
    Map<String, Set<String>> input = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, Set<String>> expected = new HashMap<>();
    input = Mail.merge(input);
    assertThat(input, is(expected));
}
}
```

Comment: Это задача про (двудольный) граф в котором нужно выделить компоненты связности. Поиск в ширину за линейное время.

Comment: Хммм, с графами я пока плотно не работал, видимо настал момент разбираться. Спасибо, @StanislavVolodarskiy!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решение через граф: по связям пользователь-почтовый адрес строим неориентированный граф, в нём отыскиваем компоненты связности.

Класс `Graph<Node>` строит граф (метод `addEdge`) и разбивает его на компоненты связности (метод `components`). Узел графа - пара вида `(USER, 'user1')` или `(EMAIL, 'xxx@ya.ru')`.
Каждый узел графа хранит множество своих непосредственных соседей.

Обход графа сделан в глубину. Вид обхода (в глубину, в ширину) не важен в нашей задаче, в глубину делать проще. Компонента в итоге содержит все связанные имена пользователей и их почтовые адреса.

Работает за линейное время:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Stack;

public class ConnectivityComponents {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Graph<Key> graph = new Graph<Key>();

        addRelations(graph, "user1", "xxx@ya.ru", "foo@gmail.com", "lol@mail.ru");
        addRelations(graph, "user2", "foo@gmail.com", "ups@pisem.net");
        addRelations(graph, "user3", "xyz@pisem.net", "vasya@pupkin.com");
        addRelations(graph, "user4", "ups@pisem.net", "aaa@bbb.ru");
        addRelations(graph, "user5", "xyz@pisem.net");

        for (List<Key> keys : graph.components()) {
            for (Key key : keys) {
                if (key.type == KeyType.USER) {
                    System.out.print(key.value);
                    break;
                }
            }
            String sep = ": ";
            for (Key key : keys) {
                if (key.type == KeyType.EMAIL) {
                    System.out.print(sep + key.value);
                    sep = ", ";
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private static enum KeyType {
        USER, EMAIL;
    }

    private static class Key {
        public final KeyType type;
        public final String value;
        public Key(KeyType type, String value) {
            this.type = type;
            this.value = value;
        }
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(type, value);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (!(obj instanceof Key)) {
                return false;
            }
            Key other = (Key)obj;
            return type == other.type && Objects.equals(value, other.value);
        }
    }

    private static void addRelations(Graph<Key> graph, String user, String... emails) {
        Key userKey = new Key(KeyType.USER, user);
        for (String email : emails) {
            graph.addEdge(userKey, new Key(KeyType.EMAIL, email));
        }
    }
}

class Graph<Node> {
    private final Map<Node, Set<Node>> graph = new HashMap<Node, Set<Node>>();

    public void addEdge(Node node1, Node node2) {
        getEdges(node1).add(node2);
        getEdges(node2).add(node1);
    }

    public List<List<Node>> components() {
        Set<Node> visited = new HashSet<Node>();
        List<List<Node>> components = new ArrayList<List<Node>>();
        for (Node node : graph.keySet()) {
            if (!visited.contains(node)) {
                components.add(component(visited, node));
            }
        }
        return components;
    }

    private Set<Node> getEdges(Node node) {
        if (graph.containsKey(node)) {
            return graph.get(node);
        }
        Set<Node> edges = new HashSet<Node>();
        graph.put(node, edges);
        return edges;
    }

    private List<Node> component(Set<Node> visited, Node node) {
        List<Node> component = new ArrayList<Node>();
        Stack<Node> stack = new Stack<Node>();
        stack.push(node);
        while (!stack.empty()) {
            Node n = stack.pop();
            if (!visited.contains(n)) {
                visited.add(n);
                component.add(n);
                for (Node nn : graph.get(n)) {
                    stack.push(nn);
                }
            }
        }
        return component;
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ javac ConnectivityComponents.java && java ConnectivityComponents 
> user1: lol@mail.ru, foo@gmail.com, ups@pisem.net, aaa@bbb.ru, xxx@ya.ru
> user3: xyz@pisem.net, vasya@pupkin.com
> ```